# How to convert these block of codes into non-nullable statement/s in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert these lines of code into non-nullable statements, but encountering the error...

> The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
> Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

```
             child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is LoginInitialState) {
                    return buildInitialUi();
                  } else if (state is LoginLoadingState) {
                    return buildLoadingUi();
                  } else if (state is LoginFailState) {
                    return buildFailureUi(state.message);
                  } else if (state is LoginSuccessState) {
                    emailCntrlr.text = "";
                    passCntrlr.text = "";
                    return Container();
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Couldn't you do what the error message says and add a `throw` statement at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Try this

```
child: BlocBuilder<LoginBloc, LoginState>(
                builder: (context, state) {
                  if (state is LoginInitialState) {
                    return buildInitialUi();
                  } else if (state is LoginLoadingState) {
                    return buildLoadingUi();
                  } else if (state is LoginFailState) {
                    return buildFailureUi(state.message);
                  } else if (state is LoginSuccessState) {
                    emailCntrlr.text = "";
                    passCntrlr.text = "";
                    return Container();
                  }
                  return Container(); // In case none of the if statements is true
                },
              ),
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. However, while accessing the property of the state (i.e., state.message), an error occurred... "The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'." After the null-safety upgrade in the SDK I am finding such errors in many places!

Comment: you can set default value if the message is nullable: `state.message ?? ''`

Comment: How to use packages that are not upgraded to null-safety?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

After String add "?" and return null;
Like This

```
class ValidationMixin {
  String? validateEmail(String value) {
    if (!value.contains('@')) {
      return 'Please enter a Valid Email';
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```